# I am getting a TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable when trying to perform DocumentAssembler() in google colab

Tags: pyspark, google-colaboratory, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

While trying to call the DocumentAssembler() in google colab, I am getting the above error. I have used '!wget http://setup.johnsnowlabs.com/colab.sh -O - | bash /dev/stdin -p 2.4.5 -s 2.6.5' for setup. I have looked into the available solutions on StackOverflow but none of them have helped. Thanks in advance.